# Cannot get uid when loggin in and redirecting to homepage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase web authentication and I want to get my user uid in the console of my homepage after I log in from my login page. As per what i have done, the uid is not being displayed. Please see codes below:

**Login code:**

```
console.log("Initialisation Successful!");
const auth = firebase.auth();
var db = firebase.firestore();

function loginUser(){
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(cred => {
        alert("success");
    })
    .then(function(){
        window.location.href = "homepage.html";
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode + " " + errorMessage);
    });
}
```

**Homepage code:**

```
console.log("Initialisation Successful!");
const auth = firebase.auth();
var db = firebase.firestore();

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        var email = user.email;
        var uid = user.uid;
        console.log(email + " " + uid);
    } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});


if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
  if (user != null) {
    email = user.email;
    uid = user.uid;  
    console.log(email + " " + uid);
  }
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

how can i solve this? Thank you.

Comment: The first onauthstatechanged function should log the uid. Does the homepage have the firebase auth script or are there any errors in console

Comment: Yes, the home page has the script as I get the "Initialisation Successful!" when it is loaded. No there are no errors in console.

Comment: Just realised that i was loading wrong script. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Loaded wrong script.
Eventually as Taio said in comment, first onauthstatechanged function log the uid.